# VMWare EXSi manual (console) Port Group VLAN edit

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have accidentally changed my Management Port Group VLAN to 1, loosing the host connectivity. 
Is there any way to manually edit some kind of config file to change it's value back to 0?

Host version is EXSi 6.0.
Good I have physical access to the machine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small 'administrative' interface in ESXi console.
With physical access to the server you can use 'Configure management network' in the menu, there is an option to change VLAN.
You will be prompted to enter admin password.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thanks. Do you know the name of the tool?

Comment: you don't need tool name, there is pseudographic menu in ESXi console with  'Configure management network' menu item.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I only used ssh one day, there was a std unix prompt only.